# How to remake this two lines, that sorting by asc and desc were implemented only on the react(without lodash)?

Tags: reactjs, lodash

There is one very simple application that displays a list table. And there is sorting by **asc** and **desc** when you click by the title and dispaly near title word **asc** and **desc**.
If you want, you can see how it works and all code in sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-raman-btwxc

But two lines who are responsible for sorting by **asc** and **desc** written with library Lodash. But I dont need Lodash in my app.

In method `onSort` and `componentDidMount` I comment two lines where used Lodash:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
    data: [],
    sort: "asc",
    sortField: "id"
  };

  onSort = sortField => {
    const clonedData = this.state.data.concat();
    const sortType = this.state.sort === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc";
    const orderedData = _.orderBy(clonedData, sortField, sortType);    //used Lodash

    this.setState({
      data: orderedData,
      sort: sortType,
      sortField: sortField
    });
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch("/data/today.json");
    const data = await response.json();

    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      data: _.orderBy(data, this.state.sortField, this.state.sort)     //used Lodash
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="conatainer">
        {this.state.isLoading ? (
          <Loader />
        ) : (
          <Table
            data={this.state.data}
            onSort={this.onSort}
            sort={this.state.sort}
            sortField={this.state.sortField}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How to remake this two lines, that sorting by **asc** and **desc** were implemented only on the react(without lodash)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lodash is a small and amazing library and provides much more than just sorting. But anyways...

React is nothing but JavaScript and that has sorting capability. You need compare of `sort` function in-built. Below is sort method written in JavaScript (ES6).

```
function sort(collection, field, direction) {
  collection.sort((a, b) => {
    if(field) {
      a = a[field];
      b = b[field];
    }
    if(direction === 'asc') return (a[field] > b[field]) ? 1 : -1;
    else return (a < b) ? 1 : -1;
  });
  return collection;
}
```

Usage from your code snippet.

`this.sort(clonedData, sortField, sortType);`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you help me implement it? Can you write this in sandbox? Because I begginer and for me it difficult adapt your code to my code

Comment: Basically you can have sort function in `App.js` as well. But it is better to have it as utility function so it can be used in any other file as well. Please let me know in case my sandbox is not clear.

Comment: thank you very much! And how to make that word ```asc``` was near some title? Now it appears only I click on some title.

Comment: Not clear about your question. What you intend to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-line solution:

```
const sortBy = (k, d = 1) => (a, b) => (a[k] > b[k] ? 1 * d : b[k] > a[k] ? -1 * d : 0);
```

And here's how to use it:

```js
const fruits = [
    { name: "banana", amount: 20 },
    { name: "apple", amount: 41 },
    { name: "kiwi", amount: 21 },
    { name: "dragonfruit", amount: 13 },
];

const sortBy = (k, d = 1) => (a, b) => (a[k] > b[k] ? 1 * d : b[k] > a[k] ? -1 * d : 0);

console.log(JSON.stringify([...fruits]));
console.log(JSON.stringify([...fruits].sort(sortBy("name"))));
console.log(JSON.stringify([...fruits].sort(sortBy("name", -1))));
```

And here's [a fork of your CodeSandbox with the implementation working.](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-cdn-w3ruu?file=/src/App.js)

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: maybe you know the not one-line solution? and the solution where there is no such:
```const sortBy = (k, d = 1) => (a, b) => (a[k] > b[k] ? 1 * d : b[k] > a[k] ? -1 * d : 0);```
Because it hard to understand. That is better let the solution be a few lines longer but it will be easier to read the code.If you know of such a solution please make another sandbox. And in the answer let already be you current answer where solution in one line.